# What is the default significance level for aov() function in R?

Tags: r, statistical-significance

I'm new to R, a complete newb who knows very little about R and stats. 
Let's say for example I run ANOVA test with aov() function, the given p-value is calculated based on which level of significance, 5% or 1% ?

```
> mydata = aov(RRM2~Cell.line, data = mydata) 
> mydata
  Call:
 aov(formula = RRM2 ~ Cell.line, data = mydata)

 Terms:
                Cell.line Residuals
 Sum of Squares   19.11027 104.42910
 Deg. of Freedom         2        24

 Residual standard error: 2.085956
 Estimated effects may be unbalanced
> summary(mydata)
               Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
  Cell.line    2  19.11   9.555   2.196  0.133
  Residuals   24 104.43   4.351               
>
```

Thanks,

Comment: P values do not depend on a significance level. Your decision (whether you regard the effect as significant) depends on the significance level. Just compare the p-value to the significance level of your choice. If the p-value is smaller, you consider the effect significant. I suggest reading a textbook giving an introduction to hypothesis tests.

Comment: I don't agree with the down-voting or closure-votes for this question.  It is a useful question that reflects a basic misunderstanding of the interaction between significance level and the p-value.  The question encapsulates a confusion that is likely to be shared by other students of statistics, and as such, it constitutes a valuable question on this site.

Answer (score 1):

In the output you have provided, there are reported p-values, is no reported of significance level for hypothesis testing, or outcome of such testing.

The p-value is a measure of evidence in favour of the alternative hypothesis.  It is a function of the observed data, but it *does not depend on the significance level for the test*.  The hypothesis test is done by setting a significance level $\alpha$, which represents the evidentiary threshold required to reject the null hypothesis in favour of the alternative.  If $p \leqslant \alpha$ we reject the null hypothesis in favour of the alternative ("if p is low, the null must go"), and if $p>\alpha$ there is insufficient evidence to reject the null (at this significance level).

Now, if you were to perform a goodness-of-fit test at the 5% significance level ($\alpha = 0.05$) then you would compare the p-value in your output to this chosen significance level.  The reported p-value in your output is $p=0.133$, so we have $p > \alpha$, and so there is insufficient evidence to reject the null hypothesis (at that significance level).

**So remember:** You formulate the significance level independently of the data (and thus independently of the p-value) and you then *compare* the p-value to the significance level.  This comparison works because the p-value *does not depend* on the significance level; it is an independent statistic.